# How to quickly collect data (survey) from students in class?

Tags: survey, sample, real-time

What would be an easy and simple way to get online responses from students in class for use in class demonstrations.  E.g. Height and Weight. A quick survey method in a computer class could make lab work more interesting. Any ideas? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all students have access to the Internet, they could easily fill out a spreadsheet in a public drive. Google Drive would work well. Simply create a spreadsheet in Google Drive (similar to Excel), make it public, and share the link to your students. They could then easily fill in their information all at once (i.e., multiple people can use the form at same time and in real time). You could then easily do statistics in that spreadsheet program, or export it for more advanced statistics (e.g., in Excel or SPSS).